# Isomorphic total complexes, spectral sequence argument

Tags: homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

I would like to proof the following claim:

Let $f: C_{\ast,\ast}\to C'_{\ast,\ast}$ be a map of bicomplexes (differentials anticommute) that is a quasi-isomorphism restricted to each column. Then $f$ induces a quasi-isomorphism on the homology of the associated total complexes.

I know the spectral sequences associated to a bicomplex and I guess they are the key to the proof. Unfortunately I never understood how one can take advantage of those spectral sequences simultaneously.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Yes, you can prove it with spectral sequences. Leaving apart questions on convergence and the definition of the total complex (are your bicomplexes of the first or third quadrant?), the map induces a map between the spectral sequences. Also it is an isomorphism at the $E^1$ level, so also at its homology, i.e., $E^2$, etc., and since they converge to the homology ot the total complexes, you are done. This is the idea.

Comment: Just to point out that you do need some boundedness conditions on your bicomplexes, or your claim is not true in general (and the spectral sequence proof fails because of convergence problems).